# Vertex image training & recognition of colors

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

If I want to have multiple images & multiple image labels, based on color, will Vertex train on colors?  Example, pair of pants:

Pants come in red, yellow, green, and blue.
I upload images for each color & add respective color label.

When the endpoint is consumed, and an image is sent with blue pants, will VertexAI recognize that the blue matches the blue label?

Comment: Hi @Phil Lucks,I have posted an answer. I hope it will help you. Do consider upvoting and accepting if it helps, otherwise let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud Vertex AI does not currently support defining [labels](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/datasets/label-using-console) based on color.

However, there is a feature request filed for the [same](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/215215746). You can vote for this feature by clicking `+1` and `STAR` mark to receive updates on it.